# VC Dimension of the class of $k$-dimensional cross-polytope (1-norm ($l_1$) ball)

Tags: complexity-theory, vc-dimension

What is the VC Dimension of the class of $k$-dimensional cross-polytope (1-norm ($l_1$) balls)?

A $k$-dimensional $l_1$ ball with radius $r\in \mathcal R$ and center $\mathbb v\in \mathcal R^k$ is

$\{\mathbb x\in\mathcal R^k: ||\mathbb x-\mathbb v||_1\le r\}$.

Namely, denote $\mathbb x = [x_1,x_2,...,x_k]$ and $\mathbb v = [v_1,v_2,...,v_k]$, A $k$-dimensional $l_1$ ball with radius $r$ and center $\mathbb v$ is

$\{\mathbb x\in\mathcal R^k, |x_1-v_1|+|x_2-v_2|+...+|x_k-v_k|\le r\}$.

Comment: Can you answer this for $k = 1$?

Comment: When $k=1$, the class of 1-norm balls becomes the class of intervals whose VC Dimension is 2.

Comment: Does the answer change for larger $k$?

Comment: Yes. When $k=2$, the class of $l_1$ balls is the class of squares whose edges parallel the $[1,1]$ or $[1,-1]$. The VC Dimension of such class of squares is 3.

Comment: What happens for $k=3$?

Comment: Given two sets of $k$-dimensional points which are in two different cross-polytopes respectively, I intuitively think that they can be separated by a $k$-dimensional hyperplane, so I guess that the VC Dimension under $k\ge 3$ is the same as the VC Dimension of the class of $k$-dimensional hyperplanes, which is $k+1$.  However, I can not prove it. Would you mind give me some suggestions?